# DevExpress ToolboxAnalyzer claims no reference even after repaired

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

Im trying to install DevExpress13.1 on VC2015.
but DevExpress ToolboxAnalyzer claims no reference even after repaired.
and Toolbox Repair wont work also.

anyone got an idea?

- 13.1 is only version what I need write a plugin on the Autocount(software) which is using 13.1
- Drag dll from programs files to VC make both of them not responding
  and stoped working
- `ToolboxCreator.exe /ini:toolboxcreator.ini` has no luck
- my project is .NET 4

Comment: Version 13.1 does not support VS 2015. See https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17003 I suggest you use VS 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag only DLL named with DevExpress.Xtra?????????.v13.1.dll does the tricks.

Im not blaming DevExpress, really really :)